# Int instead of Long, bug?

Tags: c#, algorithm, int, long-integer

I was performing a taks at Codility (it's content is in links below).
I can't understand why it gives different results:

1) [80%](https://codility.com/demo/results/trainingFH5VPC-SKD/)

```
public int solution(int[] A)
{
    long total = ((2+A.Length)*(A.Length+1)/2);
    long sum=0L;

    for(int i=0;i<A.Length;i++)
    {
        sum+=A[i];
    }

    return (int)(total-sum);
}
```

2) [100%](https://codility.com/demo/results/trainingUVM6GD-2KD/)

```
public int solution(int[] A)
{
    long N=A.Length+1;
    long total = N*(N+1)/2;
    long sum=0L;

    for(int i=0;i<A.Length;i++)
    {
        sum+=A[i];
    }

    return (int)(total-sum);
}
```

It seems like it treats the result as System.Int32 and it is System.Int64, I've checked it in VS. Is it a bug, or am I missing something?

Comment: Code examples are expected to be in the question itself, not in external links.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`T[].Length` is an `int`. `T[].LongLength` is a `long`.

Try this code, where `checked` indicates among other things that arithmetic overflow should result in an exception:

```
long total = checked((A.Length + 2) * (A.Length + 1) / 2);
```

You should get an `OverflowException` because, even though `A.Length` does not exceed the size of `int`, the product does. When you change your code to this:

```
long N = A.Length + 1;
long total = N * (N + 1) / 2;
```

You are now doing the multiplication with `long` instead of `int` so there is no overflow.

This code would also work correctly, even though I'd prefer the version that separately defines `N`:

```
long total = (A.LongLength + 2) * (A.LongLength + 1) / 2;
```

Answer (score 3):

In here:

```
long total = ((2+A.Length)*(A.Length+1)/2);
```

`A.Length` is an `int`, and the multiplication can overflow. So you store the result to `long` after it has already potentially overflowed.